# Hashing token using bcrypt and verify it by hashing the secret string again

Tags: node.js, mongoose, hash, token, bcrypt

As I understand, having the token in plain text in the Database is not secure, if an attacker gets the tokens that I use for changing the user passwords and verifying the email, then they could do all those.

So now I am trying to hash the tokens in the DB, same as I do with the passwords. FIY, the tokens are sent to the user by email as an URL that looks like this: `https://myurl.com/whatever/uid/tokentext` where `uid` and `tokentext` are the user id and token before being hashed respectively.

And the tokens are saved in the DB with three fields: `id`, `hashedToken`, `userId`.

For verifying a token, there is an easy way of doing it, which is, retrieving the user id (uid in the URL), and for each token this user has, run `bcrypt.compare(tokenText, hashedToken)`

But this way I would need at least two DB queries and maybe a few of `bcrypt.compare` calls.

The other way I have thought of is to get the `tokenText`, hash it and then run the Database search by checking that the `hashedToken` equals the one I just generated.

This is how I generate the token:

```
TokenSchema.statics.generateToken = async function(user){
        const tokenSecret = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');                                  
        const newToken = new this({                                                                  
                _userId: user._id,
                token: tokenSecret,                                                                  
        });                                                                                          
        
        await newToken.save();
}
```

This is how it is saved (note that it is hashed before inserting to DB):

```
TokenSchema.pre('save', function(next){
        var token = this;

        //Note: no salting is needed since we can assume that token texts will be unique
        bcrypt.hash(token.token, 0, function(err, hash){
                if(err){
                        return next(err);
                }

                token.token = hash;
                next();
        })
})
```

And this is how I verify:

```
TokenSchema.statics.validateToken = async function(userId, tokenSecret){                             
        const hash = await bcrypt.hash(tokenSecret, 0);                                              
        token = await Token.findOneAndDelete({token: hash, _userId: userId});                        
        if(!token){                                                                                  
                throw new Error('Token not found');                                                  
        }                                                                                            
}
```

I thought the tokens would be unique, so no need for salting, so I thought I would get the same result when I re-run the hash, but no, I get different hashes for the same `tokenSecret`.

In this case, I can't run `bcrypt.compare` since it should be part of the query, and comparing ALL the tokens of the DB will be really slow anyways.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? Why isn't it possible to compare both hashes if I'm not using salt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bcrypt returns different hashes every time you make a call. This is how bcrypt was designed, This help makes the hash secured.

please use the compare or use a different hashing algorithm.

Comment: I thought the second parameter told bcrypt to not use salt, guess I was wrong. Is there any good alternative to hash passwords without salt in nodejs?

Comment: Just for future reference, I used crypto in the end instead of bcrypt. Tokens expire after 1h, so it's not as important as hashing the password.